# Passing class/object error

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment but I can't figure out why I'm getting these errors:

> Error   1   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
>   Error   2   error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'

Its referring to this line of code

```
ISBN ( const char* str, const ISBNPrefix &list );
```

`ISBNPrefix` is another class in a separate header file, and my professor/school tells us not to change the requirements of the assignment.  I just don't understand why I'm getting those 2 errors.

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: Did you include the header (or forward declare it)?

Comment: mind show more relevant code?

Comment: Show us the code surrounding that line (including the name of the class under which that is nested).

Comment: you need to include file where ISBNPrefix is defined ..also is this satatement is constructor otherwise you need to provide return type

Comment: Did you `#include` the header file that defines `ISBNPrefix` before the line that is giving you the error?

Comment: I've actually fixed it, didn't realize I did not include the forward declaration.  But now I'm getting other errors which I have to try to solve, and I haven't even started working on the damn thing yet lol

Answer (score 1):

Forward declaration was needed.

```
class ISBNPrefix;
class ISBN 
{
 etc, etc.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Error 1 means the compiler sees the line of code as a function declaration without a return type. Maybe you meant

```
ISBN::ISNB(...);
```

or

```
void ISBN(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the other file with `#include "otherfile.h"` ?